PDFjs in LWC to get PDF inner String
Hi I have been struggling with these for hours, And no matter what version of the files pdf.js or pdf.worker.js I use as static resource, the resource is not being loaded by in my LWC.
I used the same static resource folder structure for lodash.min.js library, just to ensure Im quoting correctly the static resource, and with lodash.min.js file in my static resource zip folder everything loads good, but when I change the content of that zip by pdf.js and pdf.worker.js it does not load and throws in browser console: "Error loading PDF.js: undefined".
I've read some other examples in stackexchange of other people that made this library work with lwc, but I dont know if the problem is the pdfjs version that Im using, I already tried with 2023 jan version and 2022 nov version and the latest one also, but nothing seems to work yet.
This is the folder structure for the static resource:
**lodashsrc** (folder) --
                     |-**pdf.js**
                     |-**pdf.worker.js**

And then I just zip the folder named lodashsrc and I take the lodashsrc.zip generated file and uploaded to a static resource in salesforce org named pdfjs
and this is my lwc that throws the error:
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import getPdfContent from '@salesforce/apex/PdfController.getPdfContent';
import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import LOASH from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/pdfjs';

export default class Reader extends LightningElement {

    pdfText = '';
    pdfjsLib;


    renderedCallback() {
        Promise.all([
            loadScript(this, LOASH + '/lodashsrc/pdf.js'),  // Load pdf.js script
            loadScript(this, LOASH + '/lodashsrc/pdf.worker.js')  // Load pdf.worker.js script
        ])
            .then(() => {
                console.log('IT LOADED CORRECTLY');
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error("Error loading PDF.js: ", error);
            });
    }
}

